# Create MySQL Database with Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have the following query for creating a table in my database but I am getting an error:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    accountNumber INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName CHAR(20),
    lastName CHAR(20),
    courseID VARCHAR(6),
    grade DOUBLE(3)
)
```

The error I am getting is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You dont need NOT NULL if declaring a Primary Key...because that key always needs to be available